# How to wait to the data across multiple components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, rxjs

In my vue application I have X, Y, Z components, each component need to have `users` data from vuex.

Each component display another data but it based on the `users` data. this is mean the component can't be loaded unless the `users` data is resolved.

So I need **from the X/Y/Z component** to send a action to load the `users` data. and each component is waiting for the data using (await `insertToStore`, `insertToStore` is just my function that dispatch an action and mutate the store and after that the promise is resolved).

the problem is of course I gets duplicate http calls to the api.

I need each component to be a "blackbox". each responsible to gets the data regardless another components.

**So be able to send data via the parent it is miss the purpose of be "black box".**

And I need a solution to call the data but if the data is already fetching then wait until it's done. and when its done then each subscriber to this data will gets the data.

I think to use `rxjs` but I looking for a vue solution or JavaScript solution because I don't want to insert `rxjs` if I don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use events for this.
So the idea is to create a parent component which will get information about users. And after it will receive this data, it will `$emit` the event.

In general, you'd have situation when all of your components will wait until the parent's "Hey, guys. I've just received the data here. Feel free to render. :)".

Comment: no the component should be "black box" without any parent to pass the data into them

Comment: Then you could try to save the state of dispatching in the Vuex and due to it's value decide: make another dispatch, or not.

So 
`if (!this.$store.state.isUserDataDispatching) { 
   *run dispatch and set this.$store.state.isUserDataDispatching into the true* 
} else {
   *get the data from Vuex*
}
`

Answer (score 0):

Try getters in Vuex: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html

And in main/parent component use dispatch to get user data.

Comment: no. the component should be "black box" without any parent to pass the data into them

Comment: The parent will not pass data to the component but it will fetch it from the store using getters. But in order to fetch user details, you have to make a call somewhere.

Comment: the problem with this each parent should be aware to the needs of the components. so it's like the component depend on the parent. which is kind of problem. if I want to sometimes have the components and sometime not, I need to fetch the data anyway regard less if the components X,Z,Y exist or not.